# Paranormal comedy series from the '80s

Tags: story-identification, tv

It was a T.V. series, not a classic one, a mix between paranormal stuff investigation and comedy. I remember the generic, the music was entertaining. I think there have not been many episodes but I'm not sure.

It was aired in the 80's.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: If it was animated it kind of sounds like The Real Ghostbusters which aired from 1986 to 1991

Answer (score 0):

This definitely sounds like it's describing Mork & Mindy.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_%26_Mindy

Whilst premiering in the 1970s, this continued into the 1980s, and had  94 episodes, which could be seen as not many if compared to, say, Doctor Who, which has over 800 episodes according to Wikipedia (can't post link due to low rep).

I doubt anyone could argue that this doesn't contain comedy, and in episode 6 of season 1, a reporter offers a reward for proof of alien life, and Mork hands himself in (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0651214/), which is what made me think this fit the bill in terms of paranormal investigation, aside from the obvious fact that Mork is an alien.

I found the music in the theme song to be very entertaining, although I doubt that this would be to everyone's taste.

Comment: Please elaborate. What points match the OP's requirements? At this point, this is a 'link-only' answer.

Comment: This answer would be much better if it explained why that might be the right answer, and what parts of the show match the description.

Comment: There is no paranormal investigation in Mork & Mindy.

Comment: I checked but it's is not that. Maybe the series was more on the beggining of the 90'. Thanks anyway